# Received an unexpected check for a "settlement" - should I cash it?

Tags: settlement

I received a check in the mail for about $1000.  It's from "Huntington National Bank", and the issuer is "Saylor v. RealPage Inc. c/o Settlement Administrator".  I've never heard of these people or this settlement.  What's going on?

The letter attached to the check includes the following excerpts:

> payment you are entitled as a Settlement Class Member Who Disputed or a Claiming Settlement Class Member from the Claims Fund in the Saylor v. RealPage, Inc settlement

> pertains to a lawsuit under the Fair Credit Reporting Act

> you will be sent a Form 1099 reflecting the total amount received in 2023

> cash or deposit this check within 60 days

Comment: Searching Google shows that Saylor v. RealPage is an actual case and you could read all about it; maybe it will be more clear whether it applies to you.  If you want general advice about cashing an unexpected check, that's a better question for Money.SE.

Comment: @NateEldredge I did a search and found the website - it seems sparse on information. 
 Since i've never heard of these entities or this lawsuit I wanted to get opinions from here.

Comment: I think it is very much a legal question as to whether certain legal advantages are not forfeited in the gesture of cashing the check: does it constitute acceptance of the settlement order where OP may otherwise be entitled to claim more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a class action lawsuit, [Joshua Saylor v. RealPage, Inc.](https://unicourt.com/case/pc-db5-saylor-v-realpage-inc-1119122), where it is alleged that

> Defendant fails to take reasonable steps to ensure that its reports do
> not inaccurately identify people as sex offenders. Defendant routinely
> fails to consult either the United States Department of Justice’s
> National Sex Offender Website or the online state sex offender
> searchable databases before falsely labeling consumers, including
> Plaintiff, as sex offenders. Based on Defendant’s pattern and practice
> of related violations, Plaintiff asserts FCRA and NJ FCRA claims on
> behalf of himself and the Classes

[A settlement](https://www.sorsettlement.com/) was proposed; they indicate that if you "do nothing" then you would get about $300, but the amount depends on circumstances.

There's no way to know why you received a check at all: perhaps you rented a residence and were "screened" by the offending company.

Comment: That is in the nature of class-action settlements: you just have to be in the class. I got as bit of money because "they" detected that I had passed through Oregon and *might* have bought gas, and somehow got damaged.

Comment: @TacoVia-ShutupaboutMonica In a very fancy case: anyone that had bought a CD with credit card was paid about 4 bucks at one point, because os something the music industry did and brought a class action. The whole case was in the high millions, but with dozens of millions that got the settlement... yea...